# Python selenium copy all options from drop down list

Tags: selenium, python-3.8

I have an html which looks as following:

```
<select class="v-select-select" size="1" tabindex="0"><option value="1">opt1_AGG</option><option value="2">opt2_AGG</option></select>
```

This is part of dropdown and I have access to xml path information. So, I wanted to try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
xpathLoc = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/select'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, int(np.random.uniform(low=10, high=15, size=(1,))[0]))
browser.get("mysite.com")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpathLoc)))
```

I want to get the following information in a list and desired output variable is:

```
['opt1_AGG', 'opt2_AGG']
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following. Get the select class with v-select-select and than loop through it's option tag getting the text.

```
select_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='v-select-select']")   
options = [x.text for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
```

Or

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
select_box = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='v-select-select']"))
options = [x.text for x in select_box.options]
```

Comment: why can I not use "EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH...))" ? Or rather how to use that.

Comment: You can use webdriver waits which helps stabilizes finding elements but this was just an example for obtaining option text for all values in your select tag.

Comment: select_box=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,""))) would do it. As long as your duration is a valid number.

Comment: wait=Webdriverwait(browser, 1) where the 2nd value is in seconds.

Comment: Only thing is if it's not found it may be in a iframe or shadow root so check prior.